# Is it possible to remove this conditional statement?

Tags: c++, performance, bit-manipulation

I'm writing a solver for a simple game and when I profile my code, these lines are eating up 40% of the CPU time (via the Visual Studio profiler when run against a Release build).

```
unsigned int notVisited, move; // initialized outside of this code
bool pathFree = (notVisited & move) == move;
if (pathFree) successors |= move;
```

I suspect the actual slow down is the branch just below that line and compiling with optimizations is causing it to find the wrong line.  All of this happens in a loop that runs about 10 times per function call.  Is there some bit magic that can perform the above lines without the need for the branch?

Comment: Have you looked at the generated assembly language to see the *truth*?

Comment: If `move` is always a single bit, you can replace all that with `successors |= (notVisited & move);`.

Comment: `successors |= pathFree * move;` ? That's one multiplication though. `successors |= unsigned(0 - pathFree) & move;` may be better but thats an underflow..

Comment: @PeteBecker `move` is not always a single bit.  It represents a full path in the space and all locations on that path have to be free for the move to be legal in this game.

Comment: You can change it, but there is already no *need* for a branch, that's just one possible implementation. It could easily compile to a `cmov`, though it didn't. In [my tests](https://godbolt.org/g/nfPght), using a ternary sufficiently re-rolled the random code generator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sad thing is, any answer given here will not make any practical sense to you until you compare the assembly output of your code and proposed version, on your compiler with its settings, and all the surrounding code.

Speaking just from the perspective of code brevity, I liked [the comment by Pete Becker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44785276/is-it-possible-to-remove-this-conditional-statement#comment76551495_44785276)

Comment: Indeed, my hunch was wrong.  It was actually generating a `cmovene` and the real reason it was saying this line was taking so long is because when the optimizer jumbles up all the instructions, the rest of the loop falls under this line.  I think the real culprit is a memory lookup inside this loop.

Answer (score 5):

This, perhaps?

```
successors |= (move & -((int) pathFree));
```

If `pathFree` is false, `(int) pathFree` is 0, so the entire right side is 0 and the `|=` does nothing.

If `pathFree` is true, `(int) pathFree` is 1, which negated is -1 so all bits are 1, so the entire right side evaluates to `move`.

I doubt it's faster, though. You end up doing a memory write in both cases, where previously it could be avoided if the condition was false.